# iOS app works fine in simulator but Apple rejected due to an EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, xamarin

Apple has returned my application due to a crash. But the application works well on all simulators.

I am using Xamarin with Microsoft Visual Studio and SDK 11. The only task of the application is to show a website and information of a company.

It is my first time that I work with iOS. For this reason I do not understant the Apple answer.

The file that apple gives me is this:

```
{"app_name":"ColorNews.iOS","timestamp":"2017-11-06 12:57:29.52 -0800","app_version":"1.01","slice_uuid":"29054f34-e4d7-3459-8269-27245b14d8ad","adam_id":1299723772,"build_version":"1.01","bundleID":"colornews.Aljamir.com","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.1 (15B93)","incident_id":"B423DB2C-223C-410A-8D76-476A74EC1A54","name":"ColorNews.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: B423DB2C-223C-410A-8D76-476A74EC1A54
CrashReporter Key:   cac3035154ad4b589b77fd30cfea229fc2cfaf20
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             ColorNews.iOS [3713]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/183739E5-CC74-4935-BFFA-F5FB944F2424/ColorNews.iOS.app/ColorNews.iOS
Identifier:          colornews.Aljamir.com
Version:             1.01 (1.01)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           colornews.Aljamir.com [1039]


Date/Time:           2017-11-06 12:57:29.4363 -0800
Launch Time:         2017-11-06 12:57:29.3494 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1 (15B93)
Baseband Version:    6.17.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842e9348 0x1842c8000 + 136008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fd344 0x1843fa000 + 13124
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018425905c 0x1841f6000 + 405596
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184258fc4 0x1841f6000 + 405444
4   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bdd0d8 0x100f84000 + 12947672
5   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bd813c 0x100f84000 + 12927292
6   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101aade90 0x100f84000 + 11706000
7   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101af8ed8 0x100f84000 + 12013272
8   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101af8a54 0x100f84000 + 12012116
9   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bdd1d0 0x100f84000 + 12947920
10  ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101be0f1c 0x100f84000 + 12963612
11  ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000100fa4414 0x100f84000 + 132116
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001841ba56c 0x1841b9000 + 5484

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fac1c 0x1843fa000 + 3100

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fac1c 0x1843fa000 + 3100

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842e9150 0x1842c8000 + 135504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fed30 0x1843fa000 + 19760
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001839a2f34 0x18399b000 + 32564
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba45dd0 0x18b100000 + 9723344
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba45ca4 0x18b100000 + 9723044
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba45b28 0x18b100000 + 9722664
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018ba45e20 0x18b100000 + 9723424
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc31c 0x1843fa000 + 8988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc1e8 0x1843fa000 + 8680
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fac28 0x1843fa000 + 3112

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842c8bc4 0x1842c8000 + 3012
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842c8a3c 0x1842c8000 + 2620
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184779c74 0x184690000 + 957556
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184777840 0x184690000 + 948288
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184697fb8 0x184690000 + 32696
5   WebCore                         0x000000018c50be04 0x18c4ca000 + 269828
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc31c 0x1843fa000 + 8988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc1e8 0x1843fa000 + 8680
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fac28 0x1843fa000 + 3112

Thread 5 name:  SGen worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001842e9150 0x1842c8000 + 135504
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fed30 0x1843fa000 + 19760
2   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bbdb6c 0x100f84000 + 12819308
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc31c 0x1843fa000 + 8988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fc1e8 0x1843fa000 + 8680
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001843fac28 0x1843fa000 + 3112

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000037   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x00000001b731dd24
   x12: 0x00000001b731dd24  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b4feeb80  x21: 0x0000000101d4c000  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b4feec60
   x24: 0x00000001065373d9  x25: 0x0000000101c0055e  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000101ca5158
   x28: 0x0000000101ca5138   fp: 0x000000016ee7a980   lr: 0x00000001843fd344
    sp: 0x000000016ee7a950   pc: 0x00000001842e9348 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100f84000 - 0x101c8ffff ColorNews.iOS arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/183739E5-CC74-4935-BFFA-F5FB944F2424/ColorNews.iOS.app/ColorNews.iOS
0x103650000 - 0x10368ffff dyld arm64   /usr/lib/dyld
0x183999000 - 0x18399afff libSystem.B.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18399b000 - 0x1839f4fff libc++.1.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1839f5000 - 0x183a15fff libc++abi.dylib arm64
...
```

Comment: Your code triggers the error (as you can see from the crash), I don't know xamarin, can you debug it? Can you symbolicate the crash log to see which line causes it to crash?

Comment: Also, you should not rely on simulators for testing. You need to test on real devices. You should also test your release build on a real device via TestFlight before submitting your app. Finally, if all your app does is wrap a website in a web view then it will probably be rejected for having limited functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to symbolicate that crash file. When you do, this part

```
4   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bdd0d8 0x100f84000 + 12947672
5   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bd813c 0x100f84000 + 12927292
6   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101aade90 0x100f84000 + 11706000
7   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101af8ed8 0x100f84000 + 12013272
8   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101af8a54 0x100f84000 + 12012116
9   ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101bdd1d0 0x100f84000 + 12947920
10  ColorNews.iOS                   0x0000000101be0f1c 0x100f84000 + 12963612
```

Will be the names of files/methods and line numbers where the problem is happening.

To symbolicate, you need the exact IPA and dSYM files that you archived and sent to Apple.  I don't know what Xamarin's IDE does with them, but hopefully it stored them somewhere.

If you have all of them, the easiest thing to do is probably (on a Mac)

```
atos -arch arm64 -o YOURAPP.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/YOURBINARYNAME -l 0x0000000101bdd0d8 0x100f84000
```

(the arguments are taken from your crash) -- that will tell you the file and method it crashed in.  You need to replace YOUR... parts with your dSYM name and the binary name (which I think is ColorNews.iOS based on your file)

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATEWITHXCODE

You can get the exact line numbers if you need them with instructions there.

Comment: Thank you Lou, I try this, but this is the answer:

atos cannot load symbols for the file ColorNews.app.dSYM/Contents/Resource/DWARF/ColorNews.iOS for architecture arm64.

What means?